# store sheetname in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following code . I can extract all data from all data existing in sheets in a workbook and the name of the sheet

```
foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    string query = string.Format("SELECT {0} as sheetName, * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                }
            }
```

Then I write the following code to store data in a table in sql server

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            for (int i = 2; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {

                                for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j += 3)
                                {
//Here the problem 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( what should I write? ) ;

                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

My problem is how to store sheetname in a table [Obj CA]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your

```
"...VALUES('sheetname" + dt.Rows[0][j].ToString() + "' )
```

should be

```
"...VALUES('sheetname', '" + dt.Rows[0][j].ToString() + "' )
```

since you try to insert two values but you didn't seperate them with a comma.

But as a better way, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
var command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Obj CA] (sheetname, [Rayon])
                               VALUES('sheetname', @rayon"), con);

for (int i = 2; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j += 3)
      {   
          command.Parameters.Clear();           
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rayon", dt.Rows[0][j].ToString());
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
}
```

By the way, since I didn't know your column types, I used `AddWithValue` as an example but you don't. [This method *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Also I strongly suspect you should change your column definition order as well like `(sheetname, [Rayon])` in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @shA.t Yeah, I mentioned that situation on my last part. It is really unclear which column has for `sheetname` static string exactly. Based on names, `sheetname` fits that but based on OP's code it matches with `Rayon` column. For name matches, I changed my code their orders.

Comment: INSERT INTO [Obj CA] (sheetname, [Rayon]) always throws errors , it seems like it can't detect sheetname from the first query in my quetion .